# .net core dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

Bit of a noob question here for asp net core 2.2
Using the built in dependency injection.
I understand how to inject a dependency into a class in a simple use case
however if I have a slightly more complex case I am getting lost
So Class A needs to call a method in Class B which has a dependency injected via constructor.
So now I am stuck instantiating class B inside Class A as it requires the dependency to instantiate.
Clearly I am missing something obvious!

Comment: You should inject Class B into the constructor of Class A, not instantiate directly. Could you update your question to include the code that is giving you problems?

Comment: As @devNull said you are unlikely actually need to call constructor... But in rare case you just add dependency on "factory" - strategy pattern is one common case where you need to construct objects rather than take dependency on them - see duplicate for details (non container specific, but there really nothing special there)